# Why must programs be uninstalled?

Tags: windows, uninstall

In regards to removing a program from a computer, I want to know why a program must be uninstalled versus deleting the program's files. I bet I can answer my own question by stating that programs must be installed in the first place and therefore must be uninstalled to remove.

However, I have always wanted to know some details as to why deleting a program's files (i.e. deleting its folder and all subfolders) does not effectively remove the program from my computer. Just seems like it would.

Comment: Most programs don't have to me.  Its just some do.  Most programs could be "uninstalled' just deleting the installation directory.

Comment: *"programs must be installed in the first place and therefore must be uninstalled to remove."* -- That's just a play on words, and shows no depth of understanding.

Comment: @Luke1018 There are programs which won't let you remove all the files unless you uninstall them. Uninstalling is not just getting rid of an application but involves removing installation files, dissociating file associations, remove registry keys etc

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like what uninstall program tracks where you installed it from and removes those installation files.. that could be a very annoying feature!

Comment: @barlop When I said **some programs won't let you remove the files/folders**, I didn't mean to imply that uninstall program keeps track but  i meant that programs would stop you from deleting them and at times make it really hard for you to simply delete them when system is using programs resources like a service or drivers etc.....

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Well then don't say "installation files". The files you're talking about are not installation files - as you surely know. The files you're talking about are the files of the running program itself, in use. And it's not like some programs let you and some don't. A file in use/held open, can't be removed. And very often uninstallers hit a file they can't delete and ask the user to close this/that or just say they can't delete the file, and the user has to use an unlocker program or find out what's locking it. They often don't stop processes.

Answer (score 4):

On windows installing a program does not merely copy some files. If also writes information to a shared database (called the registry) and it may share dll's with other programs.

If you just delete the files, then you are not fully uninstalling it.

Answer (score 2):

To remove a program you can delete the files and registry entries, that's manually removing it. But it can be tricky to find the registry keys(you may have to find a list of what keys the program added or search for them), and the files may not all be in one directory.  You also have the shortcuts from the start menu and/or desktop.

An uninstaller is meant to automatically remove it, it's a convenience, it's never necessary.  Sometimes an uninstaller can be broken and you have to do it manually.